# What's the proper way to make an Ocaml subclass with additional methods?

Tags: class, inheritance, object, types, ocaml

In Ocaml I'm struggling with subclassing and types:

```
class super =  
  object (self)  
  method doIt =   
    ...  
end;  

class sub =  
  object (self)  
  inherit super  
  method doIt =   
    ...  
    self#somethingElse  
    ...  

  method somethingElse =  
    ...  
end;  

let myFunction (s:super) =  
  ...  

myFunction new sub
```

Apparently in Ocaml, class `sub` is **not** a "subtype" of class `super`, because the `sub#doIt` method calls a method in `sub` that is not present in `super`. However, this seems like a pretty common use-case for OO programming. What is the recommended way to accomplish this?

Comment: `sub` is a subtype of `super`, as adding a method does not make it stop violating the contract required by `super`.  As Rémi points out, however, OCaml does not do automatic coercion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned by Rémi, the problem with your code is that the OCaml type system supports only one type per expression: an expression of type `sub` is not of type `super`. In your example, `myFunction` expects an argument of type `super`, and the expression `new sub` is of type `sub`, hence the issue.

Upcasting is essential to object-oriented programming, and OCaml does support it with two distinct constructs.

The first is **type coercion**. If `super` is a supertype of `sub` (meaning that semantically, values of type `sub` behave as values of `super`), and `x : sub`, then `(x :> super) : super`. The `:>` type operator makes the conversion explicit — the equivalent of what popular object-oriented languages do implicitly when you use avalue of type `sub`where `super`is expected.

The second is **supertype constraints**: requiring that a given type variable is a subtype of a given type. This is written as `#super` or `(#super as 'a)` if you wish to name the type variable within. Supertype constraints don't actually change the type of the expression like type coercion does, they merely check that the type is a valid subtype of the required type.

To become more aware of the difference, consider the following example:

```
class with_size ~size = object 
  val size    = size : int
  method size = size
end

class person ~name ~size = object
  inherit with_size ~size
  val name    = name : string
  method name = name
end

let pick_smallest_coerce (a : with_size) (b : with_size) = 
  if a # size < b # size then a else b

let pick_smallest_subtype (a : #with_size) (b : #with_size) = 
  if a # size < b # size then a else b
```

The type of `pic_smallest_coerce` is `with_size -> with_size -> with_size`: even if you passed two `person` instances, the return value would be of type `with_size` and you would not be able to call its `name` method.

The type of `pic_smallest_subtype` is `(#with_size as 'a) -> 'a -> 'a`: if you pass two `person` instances, the type system would determine that `'a = person` and correctly identify the return value as being of type `person` (which lets you use the `name` method).

In short, supertype constraints merely make sure that your code will run, *without losing any type information at all* — the variable retains its original type. Type coercion actually loses type information (which, in the absence of down-casting, is a very nasty thing), so *it should only be used as a last resort* in two situations:

**1.** You cannot have a polymorphic function. Supertype constraints rely on `#super` being a free type variable, so if you cannot afford to have a free type variable in your code, you will have to do without it.

**2.** You need to actually *store* values of different actual types in the same container. A list or reference that can contain either `person` or `box` instances will use `with_size` and coercion:

```
let things = [ my_person :> with_size ; my_box :> with_size ]
```

Do note that the type inference algorithm will discover supertype constraints on its own (it will not determine what class or class type you intended to use, but it will construct a literal class type):

```
let pick_smallest_infer a b = 
  if a # size < b # size then a else b

val pick_smallest_infer : (< size : 'a ; .. > as 'b) -> 'b -> 'b
```

As such, with rare exceptions, annotating the actual supertype constraints is an useful exercise only when documenting your code.

Answer (score 9):

sub is probably a subtype of super. But in ocaml there is no implicit type conversion. So your function don't accept subtype of super. You have to explicitly make a coercion :

```
let myFunction (s:super) =  
  ...  

myFunction (new sub :> super)
```

Or preferably accept subtype of super:

```
let myFunction (s:#super) =  
  ...  

myFunction new sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `myFunction` to accept any subtype of `super` as an argument, then you should define it like this:

```
let myFunction s =
  let s = (s :> super) in
  ...
```

...or equivalently...

```
let myFunction (s :> super) =
  ...
```

As for your comment that `sub` appears not to be a subtype of `super` in your example because the `doIt` method in `sub` is what gets dispatched when the object value to the left of the `#` operator is of class type `sub`, well, I think you're mistaken.  That's precisely what you should expect.

To allow methods in the `sub` class to invoke the `doIt` method in the `super` class, you should define them like so:

```
class super = object (self)  
  method doIt =   
    ...  
end;  

class sub = object (self)  
  inherit super as parent

  method doIt =   
    ...
    let _ = parent#doIt in
    ...
    self#somethingElse  
    ...  

  method somethingElse =  
    ...  
end;
```